# drag & drop using jQuery in a table to create a copy for every drag

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery for drag & drop in a table , the requirement is like when I drag image to multiple cells(one by one) I'm dynamically adding a div and to the div s, I'm adding span text like wise I want that to all the cells . I'm trying clone() to the compose so the copy can we created but when I drag span text also it is creating copy of 'div'. please run the snippet and see the issue.

Please Response.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
$(function() {
  var compose = $("<div>", {
    id: "data-hide",
    class: "db-click"
  });
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "xyz.png"
  }).appendTo($("p", compose));
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "abc.png"
  }).appendTo($("p:eq(1)", compose));


  $("#init").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $(".drag-able").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $("td").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(compose).clone().appendTo(this);
   
      $(".drop-able").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#slot  {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
#slot1  {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div><img src="xyz.png" id="init" /></div>
<div class="textdata">
  <span class="drag-able">hello</span>
  <span class="drag-able">morning</span>
</div>
<table>
  <tr style="border : 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);">
    <td id="slot"></td>
    <td id="slot1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working exactly as expected. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: yeah , I think because of clone() method those 2 images again copying in same cell when <span> text  dragged is there a way like write the droppable in separate function and use it so that one cell the compose won't come twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remodified few thing and this will do the thing.

```js
$(function() {
  var compose = $("<div>", {
    id: "data-hide",
    class: "db-click"
  });
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "xyz.png"
  }).appendTo($("p", compose));
  $("<p>", {
    class: "margin5 strong drop-able"
  }).appendTo(compose);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "abc.png"
  }).appendTo($("p:eq(1)", compose));


  $("#init").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $(".drag-able").draggable({
    opacity: 0.5,
    helper: "clone",
  });

  $("td").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    
    $("td").droppable('enable');
    $(compose).clone().appendTo(this);
   
      $(".drop-able").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        }
      });
      
      if($(this).has('#data-hide').length) {
                        $(this).droppable('disable');
                }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#slot  {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
#slot1  {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div><img src="xyz.png" id="init" /></div>
<div class="textdata">
  <span class="drag-able">hello</span>
  <span class="drag-able">morning</span>
</div>
<table>
  <tr style="border : 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);">
    <td id="slot"></td>
    <td id="slot1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```